# And Design slider Mark values overrides

Tags: reactjs, slider, antd

trying to add 3 marks value in slider , but its override label because of too close text.

**code is:**

```
const marks = {
  0: '0°C',
  0.1: '26°C',
  20: '37°C',
  20.01: '37°C',
  100: '37°C',
};
```

and render()

```
<Slider marks={marks} step={null} defaultValue={37} />
```

check this screenshot::::
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**This is normal.** Range is to wide, differences are to small. **It's not only marks related problem - active areas (handles) are overlapping, too.**

**What are you expecting? There is no magic or AI inside.**

**You have only a few ways to handle this problem.**

**Use css/styling to make solid backgrounds** (and borders if you want) - marks placed too close will be stacked - one visible and others covered (visible borders will be stacking indicators).

**Use dynamic ranges** if possible. I don't belive in this range of values (in practice). Min/max of range doesn't have to be min/max of values - you can calculate range from min/max values and some (percent) margin (leave ends unmarked).

Of course **you can write filter for removing some of overlapping values from the visible set.**

**Dig into sources, fork and create own, customized solution.**

UPDATE:

In some cases (simple) it can be possible to add some ***'positioning logic'***. It should be possible to prepare 'position modifiers' for some values.

```
const marks = {
  0: '0°C',
  0.1: {
    style: {
      transform: translate(20px);
    },
    label: '0.1°C',
  },
  26: '26°C',
  36.9: {
    style: {
      transform: translate(-25px);
    },
    label: '36.9°C',
  },
  37: '37°C',
  37.1: {
    style: {
      transform: translate(25px);
    },
    label: '37.1°C',
  },
  100: '100°C'
};
```

Write some 'filter' to add styles to colliding values. It wouldn't be perfectly working in every conditions but it can be enough for "add 3 marks".

Comment: thanks so much for your recommendation, but problem is we need both title visible....